# Interesting method to compress coordinates (lat/lng)

Tags: algorithm, compression, geometry, coordinates

## Task

Store about 400,000,000 coordinates (lat/lng), with an average density well above 1/(50×50) m<sup>2</sup> as efficient as possible.

## Idea

Generate a polyline going through all coordinates and then use the polyline-compression-algorithm from google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?csw=1

## Problem

Find a polyline going through all coordinates only containing short segments, because the polyline-compression-algorithm only works well if the segments are short.

## Question

What do you think of the idea in general? Do you think it's better than other compression-methods and if not, which method would you recommend for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier but similar approach would be to sort the points into a grid and within each grid only store the offsets from the centre (or corner). This will work best if you use a fixed-point representation for the points, in which case the grid spacing can be a power of two of the quanta.

Comment: I like your suggestion. Do you think this is the most efficient approach (the best compression regarding size)?

Comment: It's not optimal, even if the points are randomly distributed, but it's simple and it has the advantage of organizing points by proximity, which will usually be advantageous. Generally, to achieve optimal compression you need to know something about the data. Even if the points are randomly distributed, you could probably achieve something closer to optimal by using a two-dimensional variant of Golomb encoding. (Or you could Golomb encode by scanline, if the scanlines are dense.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a quadkey. Translate the coordinate to a binary and interleave it. Treat it aa base-4 number. Then use gzip or a statistical compression.

Answer (score 0):

If you represent the points as an image, then you can use any of the standard loss less image compression methods. You can probably save more space making an alpha-only image or taken further just a 2d bit vector of presence/absence of the point.

The caveat is that you've to select a resolution for the image. For example, say you choose             1 pixel/meter resolution, then to represent a 5k x 5k area, you'll need a 5MB X 5MB image. But if you choose to use a bit vector that should reduce it further to a 6.25k x 6.25k image. Again, that's without compression. If your data doesn't have a lot of high-frequency regions, the compression will make a huge impact.

**Edit:**

The size of the uncompressed file will be big - about 40G for a 5km x 5 km area. But you have the option to split the area into multiple overlapping regions. With compression there can be huge reduction in size while the speed of accessing the data is constant time, since the data can be indexed directly.

Comment: The area is country-sized. Wouldn't the image be way too large?